# How to make use of "&" command in TCL version 8.0 to make a proc or exec command run in background i.e in parallel on windows 7?

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, tcl

I am working on a project where I am using `FFMPEG` to capture video. The `FFMPEG` command is:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample.avi
```

The link: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl26.html make the use of the command:

```
exec myprog &
```

Here they have not specified what is `myprog`.

The link: [Running shell commands in background, in a tcl proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903727/running-shell-commands-in-background-in-a-tcl-proc) make the use of command:

```
 eval exec [linsert $args 0 exec] >> $tempFile &
```

Here the command is not accepted as `eval` and `exec` is one after another, so it takes `exec` as a variable.

Help me, with the write right command which can be used to capture my video in the background with `TCL version 8.0` and `Windows 7`.

Comment: Tcl 8.0 is so old it's hard to tell 1) how it will interact with a modern operating system and 2) how to handle it properly. For myself, I can barely remember how to write 8.3 without mixing in code usable only in 8.4 and later. "myprog" is intended as an example text to be replace with your own executable command string. "`eval exec`" is itself not a problem, `eval` just assembles a command invocation from its arguments and executes it: `exec` is perfectly valid as a first word in the invocation.Presumably, something is wrong with the contents of `$args` when you try it.

Comment: peter, can u give me any working code which will work with tcl 8.4 using "&"  or  other any other option for making the command run in background ??

Comment: Try; `eval exec [auto_execok dir] &`  or `exec ffmpeg &`

Comment: for this code:   proc a {}  { 
exec ffmpeg -f dshow  -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample-a.avi &
}
a   this also didn't work, for making the command run in background

Comment: for this code:                                                                                                            
proc a {}  { 
eval exec [ffmpeg -f dshow  -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample-a.avi ] &
}
a                                                                                                                    
I got this error :-  % source c:/other/a/d.tcl
                           invalid command name "ffmpeg"

Comment: Your second try just previous failed because you tried to use `ffmpeg` as a Tcl command. The one before that *probably* failed because the argument structure was mangled. Will `exec [list ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample-a.avi] &` work for you? I can't test this myself since I don't have this program installed.

Comment: for :-     exec [list ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample-a.avi] &  , I got   "  % source c:/other/a/d.tcl
couldn't execute "ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i {video=Integrated Webcam} -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:\test\sample-a.avi": no such file or directory
%

Comment: " no such file or directory " error. :(

Comment: "no such file or directory" means what it says.  The operating system cannot find the `ffmpeg` command in the path.  You either need to install it and/or use the fully qualified path to the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: ffmpeg works properly for other commands.

Comment: Sorry! My previous suggestion was rubbish and couldn't work. I'm kicking myself. I'll see if I can come up with something better.

Comment: "this also didn't work" is not helpful.  For the fourth comment, what was the error?  You either need `eval exec [list ffmpeg] &` or `exec ffmpeg &`.  Having `[ffmpeg]` will not work, as `ffmpeg` is not a Tcl command.

Comment: thread::create "[list exec  ffmpeg -f dshow -i video0  path/filename.mp4 ];[list thread::send  {callback code}];thread::exit"            :..... this code works but as i am working on tcl version 8.0, it do not provide support for thread package.  so I want other solution which supports tcl version 8.o

Comment: – Brad Lanam, the code :proc a {} { 
 exec ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample-a.avi &
}
a    : do not work in background. it works normally.  i want the video capture to work in background.

Comment: @Brad Lanam, if i use ffmpeg with list i.e :- proc a {} { 
 eval [exec [list ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample-a.avi] &]
}
a      :. it gives me the error: ....... % source c:/other/a/n.tcl
couldn't execute "ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i {video=Integrated Webcam} -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:\test\sample-a.avi": no such file or directory

Comment: Why are you putting in extra brackets?

Comment: can you provide me a proper code, run able code for capturing video in background  with tcl version 8.0 and windows 7, as answer ??

Comment: Is there any solution to make "proc" run in background ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this line:

```
eval exec [linsert $args 0 exec] >> $tempFile &
```

is multi-fold. Firstly, you've got a double `exec` (unlikely to be what you want!). Secondly, you've got a piece at the end which isn't being list protected despite running on a platform that quite often has spaces in filenames, making the filename be a bit of a timebomb waiting to go off (though I think it's not as bad on Windows 7 as it was on older versions, where *common* writable locations had spaces in the filename).

Now, if you were using **a supported version of Tcl** then we'd recommend writing that as:

```
exec {*}$args >> $tempFile &
```

(Indeed, this sort of thing was one of the key use-cases for the `{*}` syntax.)

However, you're on an ancient version so we have to do things the other way. It still helps that we've got the above as it guides where we need to insert non-list arguments in the overall list:

```
eval [linsert [linsert $args 0 exec] end >> $tempFile &]
```

Yes, this is hard to read and error-prone to write. Why do you think we **literally changed the base language** to put in something to address that? (Hardly anyone uses `eval` directly any more, and that's greatly reduced the defect rate in most folks' code.)

Comment: This is a TCL issue. The respondent is best placed to answer this.

Comment: @Mulvya, but the provided answer is not working. there is no option, for placing ffmpeg command.

Comment: @Donal Fellows where should i pass the ffmpeg cpmmand here :- eval [linsert [linsert $args 0 exec] end >> $tempFile &]

Comment: @Donal Fellows how should i pass "ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -b 5000k -s 1280x720 c:/test/sample.avi " this ffmpeg command as pariable in above command.

Comment: @Donal Fellows what should I pass in place of "$tempFile" this variable ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, which works on windows 7 platform, with TCL version 8.0 and FFMPEG to capture the video in background.

```html
proc a {} { 

 exec ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" c:/test/sample-a.avi >& c:/temp.txt & 
 
}
a

// here >& divert the, the log will be saved in temp.tet file and & helps to run the command in background.
```