# TCL command prompt crashed with the error "ffmpeg.exe stopped working" with tcl version 8.0 and window 7

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-7, crash, crash-reports

TCL  command prompt crashed with the error "ffmpeg.exe has stopped working" with tcl version 8.0 and window 7 32 bit. my code file is "live.tcl" which is as follow:

```
proc live {} {

exec ffmpeg -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i "video=Logitech HD Webcam C525" -f sdl2 - >& c:/test/temp.txt &

}
live
```

On the other hand same my code for video capturing i.e "videocapture.tcl" works on the same tclsh command prompt on windows 7. my tcl code for "videocapture.tcl" is :

```html
proc videocapture {} { 

 exec ffmpeg -f dshow -t 00:00:10 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" c:/test/sample-a.avi >& temp.txt & 
 
}
videocapture
```

error report is as follow :

```html
ffmpeg started on 2017-11-22 at 10:56:04
Report written to "ffmpeg-20171122-105604.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i "video=HD Webcam C525" -report -f sdl2 -
ffmpeg version N-89127-g8f4702a93f Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavcodec     58.  3.103 / 58.  3.103
  libavformat    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'dshow'.
Reading option '-s' ... matched as option 's' (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument '1280x720'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'video=HD Webcam C525'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'sdl2'.
Reading option '-' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url video=HD Webcam C525.
Applying option f (force format) with argument dshow.
Applying option s (set frame size (WxH or abbreviation)) with argument 1280x720.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: video=HD Webcam C525.
[dshow @ 03dfca20] Selecting pin Capture on video
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664898760000 orig timestamp 664898643970 graph timestamp 664898760000 diff 116030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] All info found
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=HD Webcam C525':
  Duration: N/A, start: 66489.876000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0, 1, 1/10000000: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1280x720, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url -.
Applying option f (force format) with argument sdl2.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: -.
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[rawvideo @ 03e01660] PACKET SIZE: 1843200, STRIDE: 2560
detected 1 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] Setting 'video_size' to value '1280x720'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/10000000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '10000000/1000000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 03e06ae0] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuyv422 tb:1/10000000 fr:10000000/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[AVFilterGraph @ 03de2780] query_formats: 3 queried, 2 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664899770000 orig timestamp 664899643970 graph timestamp 664899770000 diff 126030 HD Webcam C525
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664900890000 orig timestamp 664900643970 graph timestamp 664900890000 diff 246030 HD Webcam C525
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664902040000 orig timestamp 664901643970 graph timestamp 664902040000 diff 396030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664902650000 orig timestamp 664902643970 graph timestamp 664902650000 diff 6030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664903610000 orig timestamp 664903643970 graph timestamp 664903610000 diff -33970 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664904570000 orig timestamp 664904643970 graph timestamp 664904570000 diff -73970 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664905520000 orig timestamp 664905643970 graph timestamp 664905520000 diff -123970 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929720000 orig timestamp 664906643970 graph timestamp 664929720000 diff 23076030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929760000 orig timestamp 664907643970 graph timestamp 664929760000 diff 22116030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929790000 orig timestamp 664908643970 graph timestamp 664929790000 diff 21146030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929820000 orig timestamp 664909643970 graph timestamp 664929820000 diff 20176030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929870000 orig timestamp 664910643970 graph timestamp 664929870000 diff 19226030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929910000 orig timestamp 664911643970 graph timestamp 664929910000 diff 18266030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929940000 orig timestamp 664912643970 graph timestamp 664929940000 diff 17296030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664929980000 orig timestamp 664913643970 graph timestamp 664929980000 diff 16336030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664930030000 orig timestamp 664914643970 graph timestamp 664930030000 diff 15386030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
dshow passing through packet of type video size  1843200 timestamp 664930070000 orig timestamp 664915643970 graph timestamp 664930070000 diff 14426030 HD Webcam C525
[dshow @ 03dfca20] real-time buffer [HD Webcam C525] [video input] too full or near too full (121% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Tcl. The "$AppName has stopped working" is a boring message implemented since, I think, Vista, and it means that the application has crashed. So that's the problem with `ffmpeg.exe`. Try isolating this problem by starting it from `cmd.exe`. And you can try "Debugging Tools for Windows" to debug what happens.

Comment: Also try running `drwtsn32.exe` — if you're lucky it had kicked in when ffmpeg crashed, and you'll get a saved crash report for that.

Comment: @kostix , sir ffmpeg works properly for capturing video on the same platform. but, if i try ffmpeg for live video streaming it pop-up with error.

Comment: As kostix mentioned, get ffmpeg running properly in cmd first, then, once you confirm it works, try to implement it in your script. So run ffmpeg in cmd and provide the ffmpeg log. If you don't know how to get the log you can add the `-report` option to ffmpeg and it will output an annoylingly verbose text file in the same directory. That being said, I don't think `video0` is a typical dshow device name. List your devices with `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , i have uploaded the error report in the question. please let the know the right solution.

Comment: I don't see any fatal errors but it may be an incomplete log. Add `-rtbufsize` as suggested in [How to stream live-video display from a webcam using FFMPEG command on tcl version 8.0 and windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324817/how-to-stream-live-video-display-from-a-webcam-using-ffmpeg-command-on-tcl-versi)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , i tried. .... "ffmpeg -rtbufsize 64M -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i "video=Logitech HD Webcam C525" -f sdl2 - " 'code' also tried..... "ffmpeg -rtbufsize 64M -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i "video=Logitech HD Webcam C525" -f sdl -", but still i got the same error.

Comment: which version of TCL should i download  LINK; https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/     ...... for windods 7 32 bit ?

Comment: Use the nightly git version, Windows 32-bit, static.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , the above link provid 20171120-8f4702a or  3.4  version ?    What do u mean nightly git version ?

Comment: The site calls the 20171120-8f4702a version the "nightly git version" because it is generated automatically every day using the most recent FFmpeg source code (mouse over the link for description). That's why its version number changes daily.

Comment: Ok thanks @LordNeckbeard . I am using the same version.  Still my pop-up comes "ffmpeg.exe has stopped working " any solution.?? Or any other solution for live video streaming  using tcl and ffmpeg ???

Comment: Does it stop working if you run ffmpeg manually in cmd? As mentioned previously, the ffmpeg output you provided does not appear to be complete and may be missing the end.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , yes it stops working when i manually runs ffmpeg command for live streaming in cmd. When run the command the it starts its execution, webcam turns on as the flash light of webcam lights. But a white window fram comes without any video-stream and the pop-up error "ffmpeg.exe has stopped working".

Comment: All of the TCL stuff in your question complicated matters and results in less help. This is why you must separate layers of complexity and get the ffmpeg command working before you even involve any coding. Why are you using ffmpeg to play the webcam video? Why not a command line player? Try ffplay and see if that works instead.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  i am using ffmpeg to get live video streaming. How to use ffplay for live video streaming? I mean what  will be the command for live video streaming  using fflapy.??

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  why to use static and not dev or shared linking ???

Comment: I'm assuming `ffplay -f dshow -i "video=Integrated Webcam"`. I think you could have found that out with a basic search. Do you need shared? Do you need to link to any library files? I doubt it, because it appears that you're just executing the `ffmpeg` binary, so static should do.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard , "ffplay -f dshow -i "video=Integrated Webcam" works for live streaming on my laptop. but when i tried to use the same command on my engg. pc it shows me the error "fflpay.exe has stopped working".  so i want to check for "file dependencies" and most likely some "libraries are missing on eng pc" i think. so how to check for this missing libraries and dependency ????

Comment: I don't know. Sorry. Not a Windows user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the follow for Live video streaming-:

```html
ffplay -f dshow -s 1020x720 "video=Integrated Webcam"
```

 The above command provides the live video streaming as FFMPEG provides FFPLAY fpr live video streaming.